# Keep data in page after refresh

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 pages in my angular project.One of them is main page.The other one is popup page. I enter data to input tags in my popup page,then when i click the add button data is added to main page.It is working nicely.I hold data an array in my main page.But if i refresh the page (main page) data does not seem anymore.Do you have any idea?

I made a some researches and have learned localstorage and cookies.But i can send data from a page to other page.What i want to do is keep data in page.How can i handle it?

What i understand is we use localstorage to send data another page.Am i right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be done with a localStorage.

An example:

```
localStorage.removeItem('Array');
localStorage.setItem('Array', JSON.stringify(this.array));
```

The above is how you save it to get it back you do this in the **ngOnInit**:

```
this.array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Array'));
localStorage.removeItem('Array'); // to clear it again.
```

**EDIT**

Import:

`import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';`

Implement it on your component(class):

`export class YourClass implements OnInit`

And after constructor:

```
ngOnInit() { // your code here }
```

Comment: Yes. The data will be available on any other page to, Localstorage will save in the browser. If you write `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Array'))` in the console of the browser, you get the output to.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will add getting processes to ngOnInıt method

Comment: How can i use ngOnInit method? Should i add it as module to project? When i define it as function, it does not start :(

Comment: I started to learn angular 5 days ago.I have no class.My desing is like this  `angular.module('app')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController($scope, ...) {
    // controller definition
}`

Comment: This look like AngularJS (v1.0+). Current new Angular (v4.4.4) https://angular.io/.

Comment: what if I want to do this without `localStorage`, `cache`, `cookies`?

Comment: Send it to a database and save it.

Comment: @Swoox In this implementation, if I make popup as reusable component then when I am navigating from one component to another component , I want to clear the localstorage. If I write in ngdestroy , then ngdestroy wont be called when I change route url, then the same local storage data will be available for next component as well. which is wrong. When we refresh on same route then local storage sgould persist but navigating from one comp to other should be removed, how can we achieve this?

Comment: An `ngOnDestroy() {}` should always becalled. Unless you not destroy the component, if not use `*ngIf`.

Answer (score 22):

I would create a simple service which can help you to manage the localStorage data. Something simple like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharingService {
  private storageName: string = "Settings";

  constructor() { }

  setSettings(data: any) {
    localStorage.setItem(this.storageName, JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  getUserSettings() {
    let data = localStorage.getItem(this.storageName);
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }

  clearUserSettings() {
    localStorage.removeItem(this.storageName);
  }

  cleanAll() {
    localStorage.clear()
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I will inject this service to my controller.

Comment: this is useful @m33n, thanks. However, what if localStorage is removed (manually) using the devtools of the browser? When user reloads the page the localStorage will be empty. In that scenario we would have to fetch the data again from the original source? or what is the solution there? thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you said, `window.localStorage` is a way to go. You store data in `localStorage` and it will be preserved even after closing session. In angular, you can make a service to streamline access specific data from storage.

To reload data from `localStorage` as you enter page, you can use `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook to load data from storage and fill your view.

Comment: My data is in array in my main page. Right now, I will add ngOnInit method to my main page and i will get data with localStorage.I will not add any code popup page.I am right? I can make set process  everywhere in main page.

Comment: @sneijder10 Yes, you can load data in background with ngOnInit.

Comment: Thabk you very much.I am searching for ngOnInıt using rihght now