# Keep Form data if user Refresh/reload

Tags: angular, typescript

I have Form with validation like below like below

```
<form  [formGroup]="LoginForm">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" >
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" formControlName="lastname">
  <button  type="submit"  [disabled]="!this.LoginForm.valid"></button>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
LoginForm: FormGroup;

onloginUser() {
    this.LoginForm = this.form.group({
      firstname: ['', Validators.required],
      lastname: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  }
```

I have a local storage service so I tried like below,

```
this.storage.set("user_data",this.LoginForm.value);
this.storage.get("user_data");
```

Here My question when I user reload the page or if I went back/forward, the data should there in the input fields. but it is not happening with above code

what I tried link which is answered in stackoverflow
  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601155/keep-data-in-page-after-refresh) but none of the answer is helped me. So could any one give better answer which is helpful to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the value of your form when you create it.

```
 this.LoginForm.patchValue(this.storage.get("user_data"));
```

Will work if your storage service returns an object.

Comment: it is working the thing is if I have filed like `<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">` and upload image successfully, after reloading the file is not keeping . is it possible to keep this file also/.

Comment: Yes, but you're going to need to store it in base64 value, which I wouldnt recommend because of the size of the string it produces.

Comment: okay fine. is it possible, if the user type everything but he/she doesn't submit the value and he tried to reload the page/back or forward still the data should be keep in the field. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: That's really a marginal case, and it highly depends on the way you implemented your component and your overall project. If only your component changes the local storage on form value change, and you load it on init, then you should already see this behavior. If not, feel free to provide a stackblitz with the wanted behavior, and I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: Can you please provide how to do this  using this loginform ? or can you give me any related links. it will be helpful to me...

Comment: Well I'm on phone Right now and stackblitz does not work. But I can provide you with it tomorrow first thing in the morning ? Simply explain in details the behavior you want, and I'll do my best with your description.

Comment: okay thanks. this is the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wu51a2 stackblitz link. And I need  if the user type everything but he/she doesn't submit the value and he tried to reload the page/back or forward still the data should be keep in the field. Is there any way to do this?  this is the thing I need

Comment: okay no problem.. one you get free, please help me in this regard. thanks in advance

Comment: Want an explanation or a stackblitz example ?

Comment: give me stackblitz example. I can understand

Comment: Okay, I'll post the example here !

Comment: @changeneed here is the form, as promised. You can go back, reload, close & open ... Do what you want, and the form will always be populated with the values entered previously by the user : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5bwd3s?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179803/discussion-between-change-need-and-trichetriche).

Answer (score 3):

This is my TS file for this question

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reload',
  templateUrl: './reload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reload.component.css']
})

export class ReloadComponent  {    
    LoginForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private FB: FormBuilder ) { 

    // 1 - Get the values from local storage
    const value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValue')!);

    // 2 - Create the form with the values
    this.LoginForm = FB.group({
      firstname: [value && value.firstname || '', Validators.required],
      lastname: [value && value.lastname || '', Validators.required]
    });
  
    // 3 - Update local storage on every modification
    this.LoginForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      localStorage.setItem('formValue', JSON.stringify(this.LoginForm.value));
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

every time you are navigating the component is recreated, and also the form, you need to check if you have data on the local storage if so then you need to assign it to the form once the form is created